# GitHub - Remove an entire blob history

Tags: git, github

I've pushed a token reference to github and already runned a rebase do delete the commit. The commit were removed but the old file still acessible by URL from pull request merged weeks ago: https://github.com/mycompany/myrepo/blob/30ba903ea69be04a8619a8b3893a782a634f7118/path/to/file.js#L14 .

Is possible to delete this entire "blob"? I don't want to let it acessible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove sensitive files and their commits from Git history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history)

Comment: Especially see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32840254/7976758